# Proper phrase for "ending someone's curiosity"

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I'm looking for a word or phrase to be used with the word `curiosity` which will mean that someone's curiosity ends after obtaining enough information on the thing he was curious about.

Example:

> He was curious about what is inside the box. His friend opened the box. He saw inside the box and that ......... his curiosity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The word you are looking for is "satisfy":

> He saw inside the box and that satisfied his curiosity.

Example from [merriam-webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/curiosity):

> The movie failed to satisfy her curiosity about the assassination.